# Options for System.exit(int)

Tags: java, groovy

We have a command line application in which we have used System.exit(int) to exit the program and to get the errorcode in return. We have our own errorcodes those are now greater then the integer's maximum value(2,147,483,647).

So a problem now we are facing while using System.exit(int) is that when the any error occurs and its error code is bigger then integer's maximum value (i.e. System.exit(any long int)) then Exception occurs.

Now my Question is, Do we have any other option(overiding any other method of other class etc) in which we can exit the code and get a error code on OS?

```
def static logout(val){
        new Logout().execute();
        logger.info("--- Exiting ---")
        System.exit(val)
}
```

our command line application is in Groovy.

Comment: You don't seriously have two million plus different error codes, do you?

Comment: in our code first digit represent one module (for example. 2 repersents DBMS and 3 is for Hadoop) and yes our error codes are now increasing

Comment: You could print the error code on `System.err` (hopefully with a useful message too for the human reader), and have the process that starts your process read that error code.

Comment: @JoeC you underestimate the OP. 2 Billion, not 2 Million. :-P

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes we can try it. Please suggest a process by which we can pass the errorcode to OS, similarly like system.exit(int) do.

Comment: @JasmeetSingh, are you actually have some recovery/handling mechanisms for such huge range of codes? I mean if the external software handles such codes anyhow? I guess no. I even not sure if all OS support that range of return codes because return code is usually as simple as possible - "working"/"not working". If you want to let the users know what's going on with detailed message you can log anything as a system event. I.e. for Windows you when can setup traps to watch them.

Comment: You are using exist status code for something that it was not intended: a detailed error message. Consider a different approach. For example return a status code 0 or 1 describing success or error and write the detailed error information to file, System.err or similar. If you want to press on with your approach, consider using bits instead of digits. If you have 4 different error sources, use two bits instead of an 8 bit digit to describe that. Then prepare to run out of bits when you add subsystems and finally implement it properly.

Comment: Do you have a big book where the errorcodes and their meaning is listed?

Comment: @Kayaman brother actual errorcodes are just 4 digit long. but due recent changes and conditions given by upper management we have categories the error by adding module code, tab code etc. For Ex CCSAAEDDDD where CC is Module, S is Severity etc.